# open all .docs in word online

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, customization, google-docs

Hey I'm trying to make all .doc/docx .xls/xlsx files open in office online.

This would mean that every link to a .doc

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads.link.doc
```

would have to instead point to the office online preview link

```
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/link.doc
```

I'm not even sure how to go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this question is *WordPress*-related. It sounds like it might be handled via `.htaccess` redirect, or a browser extension.

That said: you *could* try to use the `wp_get_attachment_url` filter, that is applied to the URL returned by [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url).

For example:

```
function wpse95271_filter_wp_get_attachment_url( $url ) {
    if ( 0 === stripos( strrev( $url ), 'cod.' ) ) {
        // This is a Word doc; modify the URL
        $url = 'https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=' . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url', 'wpse95271_filter_wp_get_attachment_url' );
```

(This is **completely untested**, and presented as an **example only**.)

### Edit

> a) how can I add .docx, .xls, .xlsx?

Just extend the conditional. Here's an example, abstracted for clarity:

```
function wpse95271_filter_wp_get_attachment_url( $url ) {
    // Using a simple ternary expression;
    // there may be better ways, such as
    // an array of doc extensions, and a
    // foreach loop, etc
    $is_msoffice_doc = (
        0 === stripos( strrev( $url ), 'cod.' ) ||
        0 === stripos( strrev( $url ), 'xcod.' ) ||
        0 === stripos( strrev( $url ), 'slx.' ) ||
        0 === stripos( strrev( $url ), 'xslx.' ) ? true : false
    );
    if ( $is_msoffice_doc ) {
        // This is an Office doc; modify the URL
        $url = 'https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=' . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url', 'wpse95271_filter_wp_get_attachment_url' );
```

> b) instead of replacing the url can I add a link next to the normal download link that says "open online" with a link to this?

Just build your own link in your template, appending the attachment URL to your base URL, as done in the above filter.

Comment: Thanks that's really great, I guess we just need to find the conditional to identify them as .doc files!

Comment: @ameeromar See my edit, test it.

Comment: That is absolutely amazing!! Thank you so much, amazing code! 
two small questions:
a) how can I add .docx, .xls, .xlsx? 
b) instead of replacing the url can I add a link next to the normal download link that says "open online" with a link to this?

Comment: Re: the first question: just use the same conditional for any other document extensions you need; re: the second question: that's actually a separate question entirely.

Comment: See edited answer, that attempts to answer your two questions.

Comment: Thank you so much I've just tested it and it works perfectly for all of them! I only run into a problem when there is a space before the extension but that's not really an issue! Thanks - I'm not really sure how to build my own link in my template and append the attachment url though! (wish I could give you another vote up!)